# i want to check the condition in matrix and replace based on the condition using matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

Let say my matrix is `x = [0.1 0.2; 0.3 0.4; 0.5 0.6; 0.8 0.9 ;1 0.1]`

Now i want to check this matrix by threshold values 0

The resulting matrix for each  condition should have same size as `x` and except the satisfied values all other values must go zero in the resulting matrix.For ex,for condition 1, x must be `x = [0.1 0.2; 0 0; 0 0; 0 0;0 0.1]`

I found a command `ind = find(x>0)`, which gives only indices of those condition and I can get those values in this way :x(ind). But it is an array. If I use logical conditions say > or <, it will give only 1 or 0 based on true or false. It cant give the real matrix values.

Can anybody suggest an idea?

Comment: All of the elements in your example matrix `x` are bigger than 0, I don't see how you want to filter your matrix, unless you want to keep numbers less than 0.3 or some other condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use logical indexing like so:

`x(x>Value) = 0`

You can change the logical expression in brackets to suit your particular requirements. Say you want values equal or larger than 0.3 to be 0 like you suggest in your post. Then you can write:

`x(x>=0.3)=0`

You can find out more about logical indexing at the bottom of this page:
http://www.mathworks.co.uk/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html